# use the word “abandoned” in a sentence following a verb

Tags: word-usage

I want to say “we go on with life with feeling abandoned” is it correct?
does it sound like you’re feeling abandoned?
Or does it sound like our feeling is abandoned?

Comment: Foogod's answer is spot on. If you wanted to, you could rephrase a bit: We move on with our lives, feeling abandoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need the second "with", here.  "feeling abandoned" is actually a phrase which acts as an adverb (modifying the verb "go on"), the same way that a word like "unhappily" might:

> We go on with life unhappily.

So you can actually replace "unhappily" with "feeling abandoned" directly.  However, since the adverbial phrase in this case includes another verb ("feeling"), it is generally separated from the rest of the sentence using a comma (to make it clearer which is the main sentence and which words are part of the adverbial phrase), so we get:

> We go on with life, feeling abandoned.

To answer your other question, yes, this way of phrasing things implies that "we" are "feeling abandoned".  Here, "feeling" is obviously a verb (we "feel").  If you actually *wanted* to say that (somebody's) feelings have been abandoned you would need to use the noun form ("feelings"), not the verb form ("feeling"), and would generally want another verb to connect them:  "feelings having been abandoned".

Answer (score 0):

**Feeling** is a present participle modifying **we** and taking the complement **abandoned**. A participle is a kind of adjective: a verb playing the part of an adjective. Just as with any other adjective, we don't introduce it with a preposition.

Here are some ways that you could rearrange the sentence:

> **Feeling abandoned**, we go on with life.
>
> We, **feeling abandoned**, go on with life.

These change the emphasis, but in all of them, **feeling abandoned** modifies **we**. It tells how "we" feel when we go on with life.

Here are some sentences with similar structure.

> Claudia came to the costume party **dressed as a caterpillar**.
>
> Malcolm walked home from school **carrying his cello**.
>
> Ted returned from college **2 inches taller** than when he left.

In all of these, the marked phrase functions as an adjective that modifies the subject of the sentence. It does not get introduced by a preposition. A preposition normally introduces some form of noun.